# Get values from varying columns in a generic trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am new to PostgreSQL and found a trigger which serves my purpose completely except for one little thing. The trigger is quite generic and runs across different tables and logs different field changes. I found [here](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2011/05/hoorah-i-was-able-to-complete-my.html).

What I now need to do is test for a specific field which changes as the tables change on which the trigger fires. I thought of using `substr` as all the column will have the same name format e.g. `XXX_cust_no` but the XXX can change to 2 or 4 characters. I need to log the value in the`XXX_cust_no` field with every record that is written to the history_ / audit table. Using a bunch of `IF` / `ELSE` statements to accomplish this is not something I would like to do.

The trigger as it now works logs the `table_name`, `column_name`, `old_value`, `new_value`. I however need to log the `XXX_cust_no` of the record that was changed as well.

Comment: Maybe you want this trigger: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Comment: IIRC you can now use `EXECUTE` to extract fields from `OLD` or `NEW` dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need dynamic SQL for dynamic column names. `format` helps to format the DML command. Pass values from `NEW` and `OLD` with the `USING` clause.

Given these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  t_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 ,abc_cust_no text
);

CREATE TABLE log (
  id          int
 ,table_name  text
 ,column_name text
 ,old_value   text
 ,new_value   text
);
```

It could work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_demo()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('
   INSERT INTO log(id, table_name, column_name, old_value, new_value)
   SELECT ($2).t_id
         , $3
         , $4
         ,($1).%1$I
         ,($2).%1$I', TG_ARGV[0])
USING OLD, NEW, TG_RELNAME, TG_ARGV[0];

RETURN NEW;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER demo
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_demo('abc_cust_no'); -- col name here.
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bb191/3)

Related answer on dba.SE:

- [How to access NEW or OLD field given only the field's name?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61271/how-to-access-new-or-old-field-given-only-the-fields-name/61304#61304)

[List of special variables visible in plpgsql trigger functions in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html)