# Trigger with dynamic field name

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3

I have a problem on creating PostgreSQL (9.3) trigger on update table.
I want set new values in the loop as

```
EXECUTE 'NEW.'|| fieldName || ':=''some prepend data'' || NEW.' || fieldName || ';';
```

where fieldName is set dynamically. But this string raise error

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NEW"
> ```

How do I go about achieving that?

Comment: It would be much more useful to provide a *complete* trigger function and the trigger definition to go with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution:
trigger should execute after  insert/update, not before. Then desired row takes the form

```
EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TG_TABLE_NAME ||
                ' SET ' || fieldName || '= ''prefix:'' ||''' || fieldValue || ''' WHERE id = ' || NEW.id;
```

fieldName and fieldValue I get in the next way:

```
FOR fieldName,fieldValue IN select key,value from each(hstore(NEW)) LOOP
       IF .... THEN
END LOOP:
```

Answer (score 9):

You can implement that rather conveniently with the `hstore` operator `#=`:

Make sure the additional module is installed properly (*once* per database), in a schema that's included in your `search_path`:

- [How to use % operator from the extension pg_trgm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975599/how-to-use-operator-from-the-extension-pg-trgm/22975642#22975642)
- [Best way to install hstore on multiple schemas in a Postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146433/best-way-to-install-hstore-on-multiple-schemas-in-a-postgres-database/19146824#19146824)

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tbl_insup_bef()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _prefix CONSTANT text := 'some prepend data'; -- your prefix here
   _prelen CONSTANT int  := 17;  -- length of above string (optional optimization)
   _col text := quote_ident(TG_ARGV[0]);
   _val text;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.' || _col
   USING NEW
   INTO _val;

   IF left(_val, _prelen) = _prefix THEN 
      -- do nothing: prefix already there!
   ELSE
      NEW := NEW #= hstore(_col, _prefix || _val);  
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger (reuse the same func for multiple tables):

```
CREATE TRIGGER insup_bef
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tbl_insup_bef('fieldName');  -- unquoted, case-sensitive column name
```

Closely related with more explanation and advice:

- [Assignment of a column with dynamic column name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144388/assignment-of-a-column-with-dynamic-column-name/144395#144395)
- [How to access NEW or OLD field given only the field's name?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61271/how-to-access-new-or-old-field-given-only-the-fields-name/61304#61304)
- [Get values from varying columns in a generic trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354558/get-values-from-varying-columns-in-a-generic-trigger/26396707#26396707)

Comment: Yes, this is very useful sample.
hstore extension exist but operator #= not found in the extension.

Comment: @FlyBot: That's odd, [the operator is definitely included in the 9.3 version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE). Are you sure you installed it in *your database* and the schema is included in your `search_path`? I added links with details.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `EXECUTE` can only be used to execute SQL statements and not PL/pgSQL statements like the assignment in your question.

You can maybe work around that like this:

Let's assume that table `testtab` is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testtab (
   id integer primary key,
   val text
);
```

Then a trigger function like the following will work:

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.id, ''prefix '' || $1.val' INTO NEW USING NEW;
   RETURN NEW;
END;
```

I used hard-coded `id`and `val` in my example, but that is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you, very useful example. But in my case the field names are changing dynamically and I can not code them hard to the trigger. I need to substitute the name of the field as NEW.$1 for sample.

Can I write 
EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.*, ''prefix '' || $1.$2' INTO NEW USING NEW, fieldName; ?

Comment: No, but you can use introspection (e.g. with `information_schema.columns`) to build the string and then use it in `EXECUTE`.