# PostgreSQL plpgsql - variable column names

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am creating a trigger, which uses dynamic names for columns

```
NEW.name:=2222; -- works fine !
```

but

```
dynamic_column:='name';
EXECUTE '$1.'||dynamic_column||':=2222 ' USING NEW; -- raises error
```

gives an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: $1.name:=2222

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found info here: [Assign to NEW by key in a Postgres trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82039/assign-to-new-by-key-in-a-postgres-trigger)

If we enable the module hstore by:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

We can do this:

```
dynamic_column:='name';    
temp_sql_string:='"'||dynamic_column||'"=>"2222"';
NEW := NEW #= temp_sql_string::hstore;
```

And the RECORD NEW.name now is set to the value 2222.

Thank you tough for making an effort to find a solution @Laurenz Albe

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that this is not a valid SQL statement.

You can access the columns in new with dynamic SQL like this:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.id' INTO v_id USING NEW;
```

There is no comfortable way like that for changing individual columns in `NEW`.

You could use `TG_RELID` to get the OID of the table, query [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html) for the columns, compose a row literal string composed of the values in `NEW` and your new value, cast this to the table type and assign the result to `NEW`. Quite cumbersome.

Here is sample code that does that (I tested it, but there may be bugs left):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dyntrig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   colname text;
   colval text;
   newrow text := '';
   fieldsep text := 'ROW(';
BEGIN
   /* loop through the columns of the table */
   FOR colname IN
      SELECT attname
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
      WHERE attrelid = TG_RELID
        AND attnum > 0
        AND NOT attisdropped
      ORDER BY attnum
   LOOP
      IF colname = 'name' THEN
         colval = '2222';
      ELSE
         /* all other columns than 'name' retain their value */
         EXECUTE 'SELECT CAST($1.' || quote_ident(colname) || ' AS text)'
            INTO colval USING NEW;
      END IF;

      /* compose a string that represents the new table row */
      IF colval IS NULL THEN
         newrow := newrow || fieldsep || 'NULL';
      ELSE
         newrow := newrow || fieldsep || '''' || colval || '''';
      END IF;
      fieldsep := ',';
   END LOOP;
   newrow := newrow || ')';

   /* assign the new table row to NEW */
   EXECUTE 'SELECT (CAST(' || newrow || ' AS '
           || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA) || '.' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME)
           || ')).*'
      INTO NEW;

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;
```

Answer (score 5):

You already found [my answer recommending the `hstore` operator **`#=`** on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82039/assign-to-new-by-key-in-a-postgres-trigger). You may also be interested in the corresponding reference answer here on SO:

- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711432/how-to-set-value-of-composite-variable-field-using-dynamic-sql/7782641#7782641)

Since you construct the auxiliary `hstore` value from variables I suggest the simple function `hstore()`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dyn_trigger_func()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
   dyn_col_name text := 'name';
   dyn_col_val  text := '2222';
BEGIN
   NEW := NEW #= hstore(dyn_col_name, dyn_col_val);
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Faster / simpler / clearer / more secure this way.

Or, since it's obviously a trigger function, you *may* want to pass column name and value in `CREATE TRIGGER` statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dyn_trigger_func()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW := NEW #= hstore(TG_ARGV[0], TG_ARGV[1]);
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_bef
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE dyn_trigger_func('name', '2222');
```

Provide column name unquoted and case-sensitive.

Related:

- [Get values from varying columns in a generic trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354558/get-values-from-varying-columns-in-a-generic-trigger/26396707#26396707)
- [Trigger with dynamic field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713958/trigger-with-dynamic-field-name/38722477#38722477)