# PostgreSQL with unavailable parameter in function

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I have this function built using PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "db"."t_pencabutan_likuidasi_after_update"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF(NEW.status <> OLD.status) THEN
        INSERT INTO 
             t_pencabutan_likuidasi_log(id_pencabutan, id_profile, nama_petugas, nip_petugas, status, catatan)
        VALUES(
             NEW.id_pencabutan, NEW.id_profile, NEW.nama_petugas, NEW.nip_petugas, NEW.status, NEW.catatan);
    END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
```

Above is a function that will triggered **BEFORE UPDATE** of the table `liquidator`.

The problem is some of the fill on the `INSERT` were not mandatory inserted, like `nama_petugas` and `nip_petugas` which is a temporary value. Sometimes it is inserted, but sometimes it isn't. It gives an error like this:

```
ERROR:  record "new" has no field "nama_petugas"
```

How could I leave it blank when there is no value/variable that is inserted for `nama_petugas` and `nip_petugas`?

Here is my trigger function;

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
"t_pencabutan_likuidasi_after_update" 
AFTER UPDATE OF "status" 
ON "db"."liquidator"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
"db"."t_pencabutan_likuidasi_after_update"();
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the table for which the trigger is defined has no column with the name `"nama_petugas"`. Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` for the table in question. And `create trigger` statement might be helpful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `NEW.nama_petugas` exists if and only if the table on which the trigger is defined has a column of that name.

You cannot use this trigger with different tables if some of them don't have a column of that name.

Either write several trigger functions or ose a trick like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45233132/6464308) to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: yes, the updated table liquidator` had `nama_petugas` column, but when i tried to update the `liquidator` table for certain value only, i didnt include `nama_petugas` column on that UPDATE query for table `liquidator`...

Comment: okay i have edited my question, so i have to do like this ? IF NEW.nama_petugas = "" THEN nama_petugas = '' ? is it right ?

Comment: eh, sorry, there is no column `nama_petugas` in table `liquidator`

Comment: Right, and that is the problem.