# Access dynamic column name of row type in trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a dynamic function to use for setting up triggers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION device_bid_modifiers_count_per()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
  DECLARE
    devices_count INTEGER;
    table_name    regclass := TG_ARGV[0];
    column_name   VARCHAR  := TG_ARGV[1];
  BEGIN
    LOCK TABLE device_types IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
    EXECUTE format('LOCK TABLE %s IN EXCLUSIVE MODE', table_name);

    SELECT INTO devices_count device_types_count();

    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      SELECT format(
        'PERFORM validate_bid_modifiers_count(%s, %s, OLD.%s, %s)',
        table_name,
        column_name,
        column_name,
        devices_count
      );
    ELSE
      SELECT format(
        'PERFORM validate_bid_modifiers_count(%s, %s, NEW.%s, %s)',
        table_name,
        column_name,
        column_name,
        devices_count
      );
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My issue is with the execution of the dynamic function `validate_bid_modifiers_count()`. Currently it throws:

> ```
> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function device_bid_modifiers_count_per() line 21 at SQL statement
> ```

I can't really wrap my head around this. I understand that `format()` returns the correct string of function call with arguments. How do I fix this and make it work?

Comment: I tried `EXECUTE format('SELECT...)` and different combinations of `EXECUTE/PERFORM/SELECT`

Comment: Please show the errors when you tried to use `EXECUTE` and `PERFORM`.  I'm not a PLPGSQL person, but you certainly don't want to `SELECT` the code you want to run.  The errors may elaborate on whether such dynamic SQL is even possible *(For example, I doubt that referencing `NEW` and `OLD` are even possible within the scope of the dynamically executed code.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION device_bid_modifiers_count_per()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
   devices_count int      := device_types_count();
   table_name    regclass := TG_ARGV[0];
   column_name   text     := TG_ARGV[1];
BEGIN
   LOCK TABLE device_types IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
   EXECUTE format('LOCK TABLE %s IN EXCLUSIVE MODE', table_name);

   IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      PERFORM validate_bid_modifiers_count(table_name
                                         , column_name
                                         , (row_to_json(OLD) ->> column_name)::bigint
                                         , devices_count);
   ELSE
      PERFORM validate_bid_modifiers_count(table_name
                                         , column_name
                                         , (row_to_json(NEW) ->> column_name)::bigint
                                         , devices_count);
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The immediate cause for the error message was the outer `SELECT`. Without target, you need to replace it with `PERFORM` in plpgsql. But the inner `PERFORM` in the query string passed to `EXECUTE` was wrong, too. `PERFORM` is a plpgsql command, not valid in an SQL string passed to `EXECUTE`, which expects SQL code. You have to use `SELECT` there. Finally `OLD` and `NEW` are not visible inside `EXECUTE` and would each raise an exception of their own the way you had it. All issues are fixed by dropping `EXECUTE`.

A simple and fast way to get the value of a **dynamic column name** from the row types `OLD` and `NEW`: cast to `json`, then you can parameterize the key name like demonstrated. Should be a bit simpler and faster than the alternative with dynamic SQL - which is possible as well, like:

```
  ...
  EXECUTE format('SELECT validate_bid_modifiers_count(table_name
                                                    , column_name
                                                    , ($1.%I)::bigint
                                                    , devices_count)', column_name)
  USING OLD;
  ...
```

Related:

- [Get values from varying columns in a generic trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354558/get-values-from-varying-columns-in-a-generic-trigger/26396707#26396707)
- [Trigger with dynamic field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713958/trigger-with-dynamic-field-name/38722477#38722477)

Aside: Not sure why you need the heavy locks.

Aside 2: Consider writing a separate trigger function for each trigger instead. More noisy DDL, but simpler and faster to execute.

Comment: Hey Erwin, first of all let me thank you for all your answers on SO. I have recently started to deal with native SQL (I was always shamelessly using ORM) and if I learned anything at all - it was usually based on your answers. Huge thank you for that

Comment: On the topic: I swear this is exactly what I had initially (except for the second lock statement - I had it as LOCK TABLE table_name IN EXCLUSIVE MODE. Bun then I started to get errors which brought me to the "need" of dynamic eveluation. Sorry for the wrong wording. Anyway, the error with that solution is following: `ERROR: record "new" has no field "column_name" CONTEXT: SQL statement "SELECTvalidate_bid_modifiers_count(table_name, column_name, NEW.column_name, devices_count)" PL/pgSQL function device_bid_modifiers_count_per() line 15 at PERFORM`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: Updated to cover the dynamic column name I had missed at first.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer! If it is indeed making any difference in the speed of the execution then I will go for 2 separate trigger functions. It's just that their definition will be literally identical except for a `table_name` and `column_name` arguments. I wanted a single function because at least in Ruby we are usually aiming for a DRY code. Regarding locks - the function depends on `device_types` so I lock it not to change during the function execution, and regarding the table, the function applies to - well, maybe it is not needed indeed. Or `SHARE` mode, not sure

Comment: I have updated the answer just for the bravity of correct type passing

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comment to [Erwin Brandstetter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55247168/1772830), initially I have an almost identical solution.

But issue was that I was getting the error

```
ERROR: record "new" has no field "column_name"
CONTEXT: SQL statement "SELECT validate_bid_modifiers_count(table_name, column_name, NEW.column_name, devices_count)"
PL/pgSQL function device_bid_modifiers_count_per() line 15 at PERFORM
```

This is why I thought I needed a way to dynamically evaluate things.

Currently got this working with the following still ugly looking to me solution (ugly because I don't like 2 `IF` statements, I would like it to be super dynamic, but maybe I am asking for too much):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION device_bid_modifiers_count_per()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
  DECLARE
    row           RECORD;
    table_name    regclass := TG_ARGV[0];
    column_name   text := TG_ARGV[1];
    devices_count INTEGER;

  BEGIN
    LOCK TABLE device_types IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
    EXECUTE format('LOCK TABLE %s IN EXCLUSIVE MODE', table_name);

    devices_count := device_types_count();

    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      row := OLD;
    ELSE
      row := NEW;
    END IF;

    IF column_name = 'campaign_id' THEN
      PERFORM validate_bid_modifiers_count(table_name, column_name, row.campaign_id, devices_count);
    ELSIF column_name = 'adgroup_id' THEN
      PERFORM validate_bid_modifiers_count(table_name, column_name, row.adgroup_id, devices_count);
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'invalid_column_name %', column_name;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am open to more robust solution suggestions.

Basically, the second condition kind'a almost defeats the purpose of having a single function, I could have at this point as well split it into two functions. Because the goal is to define multiple (2) triggers using this function (providing arguments to it).